# Problem while scrolling a JScrollPane - Threads

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

The situation is like this:

Upon clicking on a menu item, some components are added to a `JScrollPane`, the components are resized, then setVisible method of `JScrollPane` is called. Resizing of components are out of my control. (TextAreas getting resized according to their contents. Caret updates are disabled.)

I want to scroll the `JScrollPane` to the bottom. Using `invokeLater` and a `Runnable` that scrolls the list down by using `getMaximumValue` method does not seem to work in this case (while it normally does for other parts of the program).

Is there a way to make the `Runnable` thread get notified after making sure that *everything* related to the operations above are done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing that with another `Thread`?  Could you instead use

```
JViewPort view = new JViewPort();
view.setPoint(new Point(0, heightOfContents));
scrollPane.setViewPort(view);
```

That, or something similar should do what you need.

Comment: Sadly, it does not work. It just ignores the command like the others do.

Comment: @Emre, hmm.  Sorry, but I can't think of any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You colud try to create new thread and call dummy invokeAndWait on that thread. After that, all pending events should be finished and your scroll code should work.